# cannot locate 'iframe' using cypress

Tags: selenium, iframe, cypress, ui-testing

I am using cypress to test my site what I want to achieve is the following :
under this link: https://www.glassboxdigital.shop/product-page/classic
when I click on 'Add to Cart'
[image]

there is a side panel that pops out from the right side :
[image]

I want to click on 'View Cart' button my first go was the naive one - getting the element locator and click on it, as I saw it failed, I investigated a little bit and found out it is 'iframe' I tried using 'iframe' by pointing it out as following:

```
cy.get("iframe[frameborder='0']:nth-child(2)").then(function($elem){
     var ifele = $elem.contents().find("a[id*='view-cart-button']")
     cy.wrap(ifele).click()
```

but when I ran it the result was :

```
Expected to find element: undefined, but never found it

cy.get("iframe[frameborder='0']:nth-child(2)").then(function($elem){
  16 |             var ifele = $elem.contents().find("a[id*='view-cart-button']")
> 17 |             cy.wrap(ifele).click()
     |                ^
  18 |         })
  19 |     
  20 |     }
```

Answer (score 1):

It cannot locate the element because the side panel is generated into the html when the side bar is called upon, but Cypress is searching for the element on the page before the side bar is called.

Edit the code to execute whatever scripting is forming the side bar and then use the element location you tried previously.

Comment: I did not quite understand your solution

Comment: The element locator locates objects in the HTML file, but your HTML file changes. The HTML looks different when the side bar is showing and when it is hidden. You may be attempting to get the side bar's HTML before it actually exists.

Answer (score 1):

Since cypress doesn't provide a native way to deal with iframes hence we will create a custom command, basically to traverse through an iframe. Go to `cypress/support/command.js` and write:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframe', (iframe) => {
    return cy.get(iframe)
        .its('0.contentDocument.body')
        .should('be.visible')
        .then(cy.wrap);
})
```

Your Test should look like:

```
it('Go inside iframe and click', function() {
  
    //Visit webpage
    cy.visit("https://www.glassboxdigital.shop/product-page/classic")
  
    //Wait till the Let's Chat header is visible
    cy.get('#comp-jor13ajz > .yuKeh').should('be.visible')
  
    //Click on the Add to Cart button
    cy.get('[data-hook="add-to-cart"]').click()
  
    //Go inside iframe and click View cart button
    cy.getIframe('iframe[name*="tpapopup"]').contains('View Cart').click({
        force: true
    })
})
```

After Execution:

[image]